# Where can I find a variety of "while you wait" spinning gear cog gif images

Tags: loading, gif, animated-gif, spinning

I am looking for an image generator for images that:

- Look like cogs, wheels, progress bars, etc.
- Spin.
- Are small, less than 20-30 pixels.  16 might be good, i.e. 'icon size'
- Are simple, just 2D no need for 3d image.

All the examples I found are large 3d ones.  I want one of those little ones that I can use with things like ajax while loading up a bit of the page, transferring a file, sending a large message, etc.

The android spinning gear cog is one example.

Then I can show/hide the image as I need.

I figure a lot of people will have tackled this / know good solutions.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can generate simple animated "loading" icons on http://www.ajaxload.info

For fancier ones, try http://preloaders.net or http://www.loadinfo.net

Comment: omg that's awesome!  The service is a little flaky sometimes but once you get it working it's amazing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Fontawesome (version 3) includes a few spinning icons.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/#examples

Comment: I like the fontawesome ones. It can be easily used in web(bootstrap) project. Thanks.